# Solving a system of differential equations in Matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matlab

Consider following system of differential equations:

$$\begin{aligned} X' &= Z \cdot (2.5 - |Y| + \cos(\Phi))\\
Y' &= Z \cdot(\sin(\Phi))\\ \Phi' &= Z \cdot(\sin^2(\Phi) + \mbox{sgn}(Y) \cdot \cos^2(\Phi))\\ Z' &= 0\end{aligned}$$

I have the boundary conditions

$$X(0)=x_0, \qquad Y(0)=y_0, \qquad X(1)=x_1, \qquad Y(1)=y_1$$

1. How do I solve this in Matlab numerically?
2. How do I solve this analytically?

My attempt:

```
xmesh = linspace(0,1,1000);
solinit = bvpinit(xmesh,@guess);

sol = bvp4c(@bvpfun, @bcfun, solinit);
k=figure(2)
plot(sol.x,sol.y,'-o')

function dydx = bvpfun(t,y) 
dydx = [y(4,:)*(2.5-abs(y(1,:))+cos(y(3,:)))
       y(4,:)*(0+sin(y(3,:)))
       y(4,:)*(0*(sin(y(3,:)))^2-(-sign(y(2,:)))*(cos(y(3,:)))^2+(0)*sin(y(3,:))*cos(y(3,:)))
       0];
end

function res = bcfun(ya,yb)
res = [ya(1)-1
       ya(2)+2.5
       yb(1)-1
       yb(2)-2.5];
end

function  u = guess(t)
u = [1
     -2.5+t*5
     30
     15];
end
```

The Problems i have :

1. the solution depends strong on the guess and i want to avoid that.
2. the last variable $Z$ (constant) should be interpreted as a time, but in some of my computations it is negative.

is there a method for solving these equations with respect to the boundary conditions without a guess???

Another try with shooting method:

```
function shooting_method
clc
clear all
x=[2 1]
options=optimset('Display','iter')
x1=fsolve(@solver,x)
end

function L=solver(x)
options=odeset('RelTol', 1e-8,'AbsTol',[1e-8 1e-8 1e-8 1e-8]);
[t,u]=ode45(@equation,[0 1],[1 x(1) -2.5 x(2)], options);
s=length(t)
L=[u(s,1)-1, u(s,2)-2.5];
figure(3)
plot(t,u(1,:),u(2,:),u(3,:),u(4,:))
end

function dydt = equation(t,y)
dy=zeros(4,1)
dy(1) = y(4)*(2.5-abs(y(1))+cos(y(3)))
dy(2) = y(4)*(sin(y(3)))
dy(3) = y(4)*(-(-sign(y(2)))*(cos(y(3)))^2)
dy(4) = 0     
end
```

Here i get the error:

```
Error in shooting_method>solver (line 11)
[t,u]=ode45(@equation,[0 1],[1 x(1) -2.5 x(2)], options);

Error in fsolve (line 242)
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Error in shooting_method (line 6)
x1=fsolve(@solver,x)

Caused by:
    Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue.
```

Comment: "How do I solve this in Matlab numerically?" Did you read MATLAB documentation on the integrators? Check, for example, the [ode45](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) function. It has a lot of examples where you could start. If you stuck in part of the code, post your attempts and where the problem is, so we can help you.

Comment: the ode45 functions doesn't seem to help me, because i also have endpoint conditions...

Comment: Can't you use the [Shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method) altogether with the ode45 to obtain the solution?

Comment: Also, wouldn't you need boundary conditions for the $\Phi$ variable?

Comment: no need for boundary value for $\Phi$, the system with given boundary conditions contain enough information

Comment: What are the original equations you are trying to solve? Did you make a change of variables to write the equations as a first order system?

Comment: there is a change of variables happened, but for another reason: transforming in a system with given Endtime, in the ordiginal it is not known, but here we consider the time interval 0 1

Comment: But what are the original equations and boundary conditions?

Comment: @Thales : The original equations are without $Z$ (or $Z=1$) in the DE, and for the second boundary condition $X(Z)=x_1$, $Y(Z)=y_1$.

Comment: In your shooting approach, why did you shift the initial value $-2.5$ to $\Phi(0)$? Why did you change the third DE in removing the sine square? What is the idea of the double minus? Could you call `solver(x)` before calling `fsolve` to perhaps get a better error message about what went wrong in `ode45`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "unknown parameters" mechanism `dydx = bvpfun(t,y,p)`, `res = bcfun(ya,yb)`, `solinit = bvpinit(xmesh,@guess,[Z0]);`,
 to avoid adding the additional component for $Z$.

A non-linear boundary value problem can be expected to have an arbitrary number of solutions, from zero to infinitely many. You will need to have a good idea of the shape of the desired solution to pass to `bvpinit` to fix on the exact solution close to it.

The standard in BVP solvers is to use collocation methods or at least implicit methods of a high order. These react very badly to discontinuities as introduced with the signum of $Y$. Even the absolute value might lead to an increased mesh density around points where it is zero, which might lead to exceeding the allowed number of mesh nodes. It is worth a try to replace them with smooth mollifications.